# How do I calculate interest ethereum solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

To learn a bit about ethereum, I thought I'd code up a simple loan contract.  I added a few simple properties for any loan, and I immediately ran into problems.

```
contract Loan
{
    address lender;
    address borrower;
    uint amount;
    ???? interestRate;
    ...
}
```

What type do I use for the interest rate?  Looking at the [solidity types documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/types.html), the primitive types include Boolean and multiple kinds of integers.  There is no primitive for decimal numbers.

Without decimal numbers, how do I calculate the interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solidity [changelog](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Changelog) shows that fixed point types will be included in version 0.3.0 which is in development.

Comment: We are at 0.3.4 and fixed point types are still "in progress"

Answer (score 3):

You can use another unit.
Like multiply every percentage by 100, you achieve a 2 number after comma precision

```
1% => 100
0,1% => 10
0,01% => 1
```

If it's not enough, you can use other multipliers.

Comment: Ok, easy enough.  If I add two values for interest rate multiplier and interest rate divisor I end up with any interest rate I want.  Any remainders will be dropped.